# How to get the grid data with column title after selecting particular the column names dynamically in the grid ( UI grid)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

My question here, we are using UI grid to display the data in the grid . We have columns which are dynamically displayed according to our request , so the number of columns will change . Also we can enable or disable the column which needs to displayed in the grid UI manually. Here we want to get **only grid data and column title (column names)** of the **enabled column names** on the grid ( enabling the column names in the grid is done manually) . How can we capture that?

When we tried using the export as csv or pdf available in grid options it exports only selected column and their data , but manually when we try to capture the selected column and their data we couldnt get it . (We are getting all the data in the grid .) Please help on this .We need to get only data of selected columns on the grid.